# Can't figure out why sScrollY in Datatables corrupt the Columns's size and alignement

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, datatables

I need to use `sScrollX` and `ScrollY` property for my datatables. But simply adding one of this property cause a lot of problems with size and alignemnt of the columns.

Here is a simple re-production of my table. In reality i use an Ajax call to fill my table. but i replied some data for this example:

[Example](http://live.datatables.net/Ikis/1/edit)

Here is a picture of my real page:
[image: pic]

Can someone explain me this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a chance to speak directly with Allan, the ideator of Datatables, and he said that it's a bug he didn't know about.

Here a temporary solution, quoting Allan:

> Just been experimenting some more with a proper fix - and I think I might actually have it... The problem is that the scrolling body doesn't have the same content in its header cells as the actual header - thus different sizing rules apply.
>
> So the fix (I guess it seems obvious now) is to have that same content in the body's header cells, but wrapped in a div which is height:0. Test case showing this "real" fix: http://datatables.net/clients/ciaoben/acs-web.it-fixed/test/esperimenti.php.html
>
> Unfortunately 1.10.0-beta.1 hit today :-(. So it won't be in that. But I will commit this in tomorrow for the next beta unless I can think of some reason why it wouldn't work (it will slow performance down a little, but not too much I think).
>
> Allan

For my case, it works.